# Postfix and dovecot: How to receive messages with large attachments?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

I configured postfix and dovecot on Debian 6.0.  I have set high limits both for my php and my postfix configuration file, but I am still unable to receive large email messages or messages with large attachment files (5 MB or greater) via the SquirrelMail client.  I checked the log and all seems to be going well; is there any configuration I should look for or something I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would your php file upload limit matter with your postfix configuration? it sounds like you're testing this through a webmail interface?

Comment: Define "large attachments"

Comment: Why do you think the limit is on your side, and not at the webmail provider?

Comment: Repeat after me: ***Email is NOT a file transfer protocol.***  You shouldn't be sending anything *large* via email. Even if ***YOUR*** mail server accepts it there is a good chance the *recipient's* server will not.

Comment: If you "don't receive" then you *must* have an error report or log of it not being received. Post it. Also, a few years back some guys invented a Protocol for Transferring Files; crazy stuff really. It even supports encryption and security stuff these days. Might want to look into it.

Comment: No, I am sending 5mb of attachment files, I set the limit of my php higher because I needed for upload files, my webmail client is squirrelmail, but I also read them throught gmail, I checked the logs but still... there is no message of error... all seems to be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What paraemters did you change?

On a CentOS 6 box, the /etc/php.ini has upload_max_filesize as 2MB.  Was this the parameter you changed?  I believe postfix's default max size is 10MB, so there should have been no need to change that.

If it's a PHP error, the problem won't be in your maillog.  It will show up in the web server logs.

In your maillog, do you see the SMTP transaction?

Comment: yea, thanks, I noticed I get an error  "not enough free space in mail queue" still I dont know how to set this queue bigger... any idea please?

Comment: Huh.  You have free disk space in the partition, right?